# align div horizontally after screen resize using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align div horizontally as the browser resizes, currently, I have 3 divs. As per the requirement, I can add an additional div. My problem is as soon I increase the window size above 2500, the right side of the screen becomes empty & all the divs are floating to left. As I cannot set the div width to 30-33% as per the requirement. Below is my code. kindly help.

```css
div.box-container {
  mc-grid-row: true;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}

div.box {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 326px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 55px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">

  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float` and only use `flex`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: auto;
}

div.box-container {
  mc-grid-row: true;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

div.box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 326px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 55px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  width: calc(100vw / 3);
  /*calc(100vw / number of div)*/
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. what if I want to add 2 more divs. will it be still responsive? because the width of the div is 33% currently.

Comment: @user3448925 Thanks for the good question. I edited my answer. you can use `calc(100vw / number of divs)` for the width of divs. Is appropriate for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. i learnt something new (calc(100vw / 3) )by your answer.

Comment: @user3448925 You're welcome. yes with the help of that, no need for accurate calculation of the width of divs.

Answer (score 2):

As @Arman Ebrahimi had already mentioned correctly. Use flex box only. The issue of responsibility can be handled well with media queries.

**Working example**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* or use justify-content: center; */
}

.box {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  word-break: break-word;
  height: 326px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .box {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>

  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content: center;` when you are using `flex`. This means the flexed contents will always be centered on all screen types.

```css
div.box-container {
  mc-grid-row: true;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%
}

div.box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 326px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 55px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">

  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit ~ add another div, reduce the `%` the div covers. Demonstrate `min-width` responsiveness.

```css
div.box-container {
  mc-grid-row: true;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%
}

div.box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 326px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 55px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  width: 24%;
  min-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">

  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>jfn,mnfngf,mn,mgfnbgnkjdkjgkdg</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want the div to cover the entire screen after i resize the screen above 2500. Thank you

Comment: @user3448925 remove `floats` and make the width of `box` 33%. Then you can remove the `margin-left` to space the divs & space them with `gap`. So if you want to add another div just make each div's width 25% and so on. See edits.

Comment: it's working. Thank you. just out of curiosity. can we achieve this without flex?

Comment: @user3448925 typically what I would do then after this is figuring out a `min-width` based on the contents inside each div. Then you can set the div `min-width: 400px` for example if you had a 400px size image in the div. So that when you resize downward on the browser each flexed-item will wrap to a new line once it hits that `min-width`.

Comment: if I use display-flex, will it work for all the media like mobile, tablets? as i'm new to this field, pardon me for my silly questions

Comment: Not silly questions, so that's what I meant by `min-width`. This pairs with also adding `flex-wrap: wrap;`. See my edits on the second snippet so I can show it. You will see when you resize the browser downwards the `box` divs start to stack and break into a new line because of the `min-width` set. Meaning they won't get smaller than 400 px in width.

Comment: I meant to say 300px since that is what I set the min-width at.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing the things. this will help me when the same is applied for mobile & tablets

Comment: Hi. In first case(width: 33.3%) why there is overflow-x? while `3*(33.3%) ~ 100%`! Also in the second case(width: 24%) why places two divs on any line instead of four divs?